# Vite and VueJS3 and .mount('#app'); NOT WORKING

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

I've been reading on the internet, all foruns and communities that are some issues with Vite+VueJS3 at the `.mount("#app")` point.
I am facing this exactly problem and can't figure how to fix it!

`Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character` pointing to `app.mount('#app');` at `app.js`.

Let's see some code:
`vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

`app.js`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Lead from './components/Lead.vue';
import Atendimento from './components/Atendimento.vue';

const app = createApp({
  components: {
    Lead,
    Atendimento,
    render: h => h(app)
  }
});

app.component('atendimento', Atendimento);
app.component('lead', Lead);
app.mount('#app');
```

The `app.blade.php` witch all Blade extends has the `<div id="app">` clearerly, so there is no problem (I guess) with disposition of the script.

You can see, at `vite.config.js` that there are a alias pointing to the dev compiler:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
```

Right now I am pulling all my hair out of my head!
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I didn't want to migrate.

You had to add the component inside you div with the mounted id like so:

```
<div id="app">
<your-component></your-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to change the import from:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
```

to

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'
```

Once I did this, the production build with Vite worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't solve this issue, I decided to migrate from `Vite` to `Laravel-mix` and used [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat/eca89f2d-bd0c-4c46-b5a2-699a174ba220) to help.
Check this out:

Here are the steps to migrate from ViteJS to Laravel-mix in a Laravel project:

Install Laravel-mix by running `npm install laravel-mix`.
Create a new file, `webpack.mix.js` at the root of your project.
Copy the following code into webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

```
In your package.json file, change the scripts section from:
```

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build"
}
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npm run development",
  "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
}
```

```
Remove the vite.config.js file, since Laravel-mix uses the webpack.mix.js file to configure webpack

Remove the vite package by running `npm uninstall vite`

Test the migration by running npm run dev and verify that your JavaScript and CSS assets are being compiled as expected.
```

That's it! You have successfully migrated from ViteJS to Laravel-mix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for a production-build seems to be the place there the **@vite** is included.

Change your app.blade to this and it will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>How To Install Vue 3 in Laravel 9 with Vite</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
</div>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Vite/Vue3 setup working with in-dom templates. The original issue was that it rendered fine in `dev` but was completely empty in `prod`. Root cause was that I used `const app = createApp(App)` where `App` was just an empty Vue file. This worked in dev, but for prod I needed `const app = createApp({})` and ditch the `App` .

Here are the relevant bits of code:

```js
// main.js
import 'vite/modulepreload-polyfill';

import './style.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import HelloWorld from './views/HelloWorld.vue'

if (document && document.getElementById('app')) {
    window.onload = function() {
        const pinia = createPinia()
        const app = createApp({})
        app.use(pinia)

        // register your components here
        app.component('hello-world', HelloWorld)

        app.mount("#app")
    }
}
```

Then...

```html
<!-- somewhere in your html -->
<section id="app" class="container-fluid">
  <hello-world></hello-world>
</section>
```